# Crop ellipse to fit in between other shapes in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, crop, shapes, tikz-shape, irregular-shape

Assuming I have two shapes and I want to add a circular shape (like an `ellipse`). How can I crop this ellipse so that it fits in between the other shapes like sketched below? I don't want to add white borders around the shapes, though, since I want to keep the empty space transparent.

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill  (-4,2) rectangle (-1,1.5);
\fill  (-3.5,1.25) rectangle (-0.5,0.75);
\fill  (-1.6,1.35) ellipse (0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Since the rectangle shapes in the example above may be a bit too specific, I want to give a more complex example of what I would like to achieve; this time with more complex shapes overlapping my `ellipse`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pattern[pattern=checkerboard,pattern color=black!30] (-5,0) rectangle (0,3);
\newcommand{\myspace}{0.5}
\fill  (-4,2) rectangle (-1,1.5);
\fill  (-3.5,1.25) rectangle (-0.5,0.75);
\clip ([yshift=\myspace] -2,1.25) rectangle ([yshift=-\myspace] -1,1.5);
\fill  (-1.6,1.35) ellipse (0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Shapes on checkerboard pattern]

**Edit:** Here is one way to achieve the updated question using `tikzfadingfrompicture` :

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings, patterns}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myfading]
\draw[draw=transparent!100, ultra thick, fill=transparent!0] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
\draw[draw=transparent!100, ultra thick, fill=transparent!0] (-2,-1) -- (0,0) -- (-1,2.5) -- (-2,2) -- cycle;
\draw[draw=transparent!100, ultra thick, fill=transparent!0] (0,1) ellipse [x radius=0.5, y radius=0.8];
\draw[draw=transparent!100, ultra thick, fill=transparent!0] (0.2,-0.5) -- (1,1.5) -- (2,-0.5) -- cycle;
\draw (0,0) circle[radius=10]; %encompassing circle for alignment 
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pattern[pattern=checkerboard,pattern color=black!30] (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
\fill[path fading=myfading, fit fading=false] (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Shapes on checkerboard]

Comment: This looks great! How can this be applied to more general overlapping forms which are not as "perfect" as rectangles? E.g. other ellipses, irregular n-gons etc.?

Comment: I added another, more general example!

Comment: @TiMauzi: No one is forcing you to use a `rectangle` within `clip` - it can be any shape. It can be a pain to find the correct clipping path, so you might prefer using a `tikzfadingfrompicture` like in my updated answer.